# If Service produce event to one topic, only this service have to consume processed event from another topic (Kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have to implement event driven architecture services with Kafka (Java tech stack).
I drew example:

[image: my services with producers and consumers]

Imagine that I have 3 external producers (Ms1, Ms2, Ms3), who sends events in to one topic, which my service reads. After receiving event, my service processing some business logic and than pushes event to another topic. Ms1, Ms2, Ms3 subscribe on this topic and listen what come in. My goal is: if Ms1 sent event to topic-1, only Ms1 must received response event from topic-2 (despite the fact that other Consumers are listening to this topic too, they are forbidden to receive event belong to Ms1). If Ms2 sent event to topic-1, than only Ms2 must received event from topic-2.

And I don't know how many consumers/producer will be. It's floating amount. Today it can be 3 external producers/consumers, tomorrow maybe 30 and so on. They can subscribe and unsubscribe.

Comment: [This](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-topic-architecture-amp-partitions) should help

Comment: This seems to be the use case to send messages/events with keys. Then you can decide in your business logic to where forward messages/events based on theur keys.

Comment: Look slike subject for partitioning: https://www.instaclustr.com/the-power-of-kafka-partitions-how-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-kafka-cluster/#:~:text=Partitions%20are%20the%20main%20concurrency,as%20partitions%20for%20a%20topic.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka records shouldn't "belong" to particular services, IMO, this is mostly metadata about data lineage; maybe that information will be valuable for some other consumer use case that you've not considered yet.
If you have multiple consumers from one topic, there's no logic outside of filtering and explicit partition assignments that would get "all M1 producer events to all M1 consumers"

If you want to lock down access to topics to particular clients, use ACLs and certificates. Otherwise, there's nothing stopping new consumer groups from subscribing to whatever topics they want